# Adjust “home” address in Apple Maps without affecting Autofill, etc

Tags: ios, contacts, maps, navigation

When I ask Siri to “direct me home,” I really mean that I want her to take me to my parking spot, which is about a block away from what Maps considers to be the location of my building. Due to one-way streets this can actually make a significant difference to the resulting navigation directions.

I considered updating my contact card “home” address to the address of my lot, so I am able to continue to ask Siri to “direct me home,” use the “Home” button on CarPlay, etc. But I still want any non-maps-related services (such as Safari AutoFill) to know my real residential address.

Is there a way iOS can distinguish these two concepts?

Comment: I'd have to verify for myself, but iirc you can set multiple home addresses to your contact card, and that can show up as multiple homes in Maps. When you prompt Siri, it'll ask you "which home?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There’s an easy way to do this from your iPhone :

- Open the Maps app
- Tap on ⓘ to open the settings
- Select “Report an issue” and “Home”
- You can then move the pin on the map without changing your address.

Dont click on “Report to Apple” and select “Save on my device”. It won’t work otherwise.